# Convert Sys.time() to character without losing timezone?

Tags: r

How can we convert the output of `Sys.time()` to character class without losing the timezone information (in this case the `AEDT`) ?

```r
Sys.time()
# [1] "2019-10-17 21:54:07 AEDT"

Sys.time() %>% as.character()
# [1] "2019-10-17 21:54:07"

# Desired output
"2019-10-17 21:54:07 AEDT"
```

Please note that I wish to avoid using any external libraries (just base R)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you a character

```r
x <- format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
str(x)
# chr "2019-10-17 22:13:45 AEDT"
```

`usetz` is `FALSE` by default, set that to `TRUE` so it persists during the conversion.